# Phantomjs cookie authentication failed to capture and print the web page

Tags: cookies, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to print the webpage and create a pdf. As the UI needs the user's  authentication before finding the data, I used persistent cookies to authenticate the user. But somehow I got login screen every time in the created PDF. I observed that the user authenticated successfully and also the result's webpage showing proper result (debug logs showing the proper data array) but while printing the web page or creating a PDF, it somehow gets the login screen. Sometimes I observed that I got two different cookies in my PHP code while getting the report data and in javascript 'document.cookies'.

Please let me know how can I fix this.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), 
    system = require('system'), t, address; 

page.settings.userName = 'myusername'; 
page.settings.password = 'mypassword'; 

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: scrape.js '); 
    phantom.exit(); 
} else { 
    t = Date.now(); 
    address = system.args[1]; 

    page.open(address, function (status) { 
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address'); 
        } else { 
            t = Date.now() - t; 
            var title = page.evaluate(function() { return document.title;})
            console.log('Page title is ' + title);
            console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec'); 
        } 
        phantom.exit(); 
    });
}
```

Another piece of code of sending a cookie file

```
bin/phantomjs --cookies-file=/tmp/cookies.txt --disk-cache=yes --ignore-ssl-errors=yes /phantomjs/pdf.js 'username' 'params' '/tmp/phantomjs_file' /tmp/phantom_pdf.pdf
```

And

```
phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt examples/rasterize.js localhost:7000/reports /tmp/report.pdf
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same cookies file? In the first call it is `/tmp/cookies.txt` and in the next it is `cookies.txt`. Is `--disk-cache=yes` necessary for you?